# NOT of 64 bit number giving wrong results in c

Tags: c, 64-bit, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

there are two numbers a and b, both 64 bits.

Code:

a = a|b;

if(!(a&b)){
}

Now in the above scenario b's 34th bit is on and a have some bits on.
So, according to the situation !(a&b) should result in 0 but the code is entering in the if loop which is wrong. The problem is that !(a&b) is giving 1 instead of 0. Any reasons?

Comment: After `a = a|b;` you have `(a&b) == b`. So I see three possibilities: 1) `b` is 0, contrary to what you think, 2) your actual code is different, 3) the compiler is buggy.

Comment: b = 1<<33 which is not 0 and the actual code uses the same situation and compiler is gcc which is definitely not buggy.

Comment: Ah, but `1 << 33` shifts an **`int`**. If `int` is, as usual, 32 bits wide, that's undefined behaviour, and may result in `b` being 0 (if the `1 << 33` appears as such in the source code, gcc does that; the shift is evaluated at compile time, then masked to 32 bits). Use `1ull << 33` instead.

Comment: actually b = 1ull<<33 (missed in my previous comment).

Comment: Can you provide example code that reproduces the issue, it would help to reduce guesswork.

Comment: the problem is with not operator on 64 bit integer.

Comment: I can not post the exact piece of the code, but the situation is exactly same.

Comment: @rahul.jain If you can not post any code it may still be useful to go through the exercise of reducing the problem to a small sample that reproduces the problem. A lot of times just the act alone ends up illuminating incorrect assumptions or bugs.

Comment: If you are asking us what circumstances might cause this behavior, the correct answer would be a bug in your code. If you show us the code, we might be able to help identify the bug. Otherwise, you are choosing to find it on your own (but it does seem like a type width issue, like `a` or `b` was only defined to be `long` instead of `long long`).

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't want to make an [SSCE](http://sscce.org/), I made one for you:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    unsigned long long a = 42, b = 1ULL << 33;

    a = a|b;
    if(!(a&b))
        printf("!(a&b)\n");
    else
        printf("(a&b)\n");

    return 0;
}
```

and ran it at [ideone](http://ideone.com/0Hif2t). It outputs `(a&b)` as expected. Your problem is not in the code you are showing us.